# Parsing arguments after taking into a temp variable in ksh shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, variables, command, arguments

I have a shell script as below:

```
$ cat check.sh  

    echo "$@"  
    for i in "$@"; do  
        echo "$i"  
    done
```

If I run the script with command line args, it prints as below:

```
$ ./check.sh arg1 arg2 "This is a message" arg4  

arg1 arg2 This is a message arg4  
arg1  
arg2
This is a message  
arg4
```

All is well till now.. -- the number of arguments shown are 4

If I take `$@` into an variable and do the same thing on it, it will behave as below:

```
$ cat check.sh  

    VARGS="$@"  
    echo "$VARGS"  
    for i in $VARGS; do  
        echo "$i"  
    done  


$ ./check.sh arg1 arg2 "This is a message" arg4

arg1 arg2 This is a message arg4   
arg1  
arg2  
This  
is  
a  
message  
arg4
```

Here the number of arguments are 7.
The reason that I have taken the arguments in a temp variable is to remove some unwanted args from it and pass it to another application/process.

Can someone let me know how to get the same behavior in this scenario as if we are using "$@"

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You need to use an array to preserve your arguments. If your version of `ksh` doesn't support array variables then you might need to manually find the indexes of the values you want to avoid and manually call the second command using the `${@:offset:length}` syntax (that should exist even without general array variables I think).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using *ksh93* for this, but it ought to work in *ksh88* as well as it also has arrays:

```
set -A VARGS "$@"

IFS=

for i in ${VARGS[@]}; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Setting `IFS=` is necessary, otherwise the "This is a message" string would be chopped up on spaces.